# testdriven.io: error in Github action, step of : push image

Tags: docker, testdriven.io

In the step, 'Push image' I got error like below.

```
denied: installation not allowed to Write organization package
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This issue is related with the permission. here are some guides

- [Modifying the permissions for the GITHUB_TOKEN](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#modifying-the-permissions-for-the-github_token)
- [Setting the permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN for your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#setting-the-permissions-of-the-github_token-for-your-repository)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed error like below

```
name: Continuous Integration and Delivery

on: [push]

permissions: write-all
```

How Can I solve this with issue by controlling a single job?

I though I can solve this issue with below code but it failed.
So, I changed the entire permission like the above.

```
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build Docker Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
```